# How do I write my REST API call when expecting two types of return Objects

Tags: java, spring, rest

I've written a REST endpoint using Spring.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/staticdata/userPreference/extUserId/{extUserId}/type/{type}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<UserPreference>> getData(
        @PathVariable String extUserId,
        @PathVariable String type) {

    List<UserPreference> userPreferences = null;
    userPreferences = staticDataService.getUserPreference(extUserId, type);
    return new ResponseEntity<List<UserPreference>>(userPreferences, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception) {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(exception.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

When the getData() method is able to successfully get the data, it needs to return the List<>. However when there is an exception. The message is to be returned. This is handled by the handleError() method. This method returns a String.

My question is:
How should the call to this rest service look like using the restTemplate offered by Spring? The return of the method can either be a List or a String based on success of failure respectively.

Comment: To explain what I'm trying to achieve here is - I need to get a string sent back to the calling Class to help long the exact reason for the failure when calling the REST endpoint. The getUserPreference throws a RuntimeException with that String as the errorMessage.

Comment: A more elegant way of achieving the same would be to use a [rest exception mapper](https://dzone.com/articles/exception-handling-spring-rest).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `RestTemplate#exchange` to execute a request and get the response as `ResponseEntity` and then obtain the `List<UserPreference>` by `ResponseEntity#getBody`.

If there is an error, you can obtain the error response from `HttpStatusCodeException.getResponseBodyAsString`.

Following is an example:

```
try {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    // add some headers
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);    
    ResponseEntity<List<UserPreference>> response = restTemplate.exchange(
        YOUR_URL, HttpMethod.GET, request, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<UserPreference>>() {});
    List<UserPreference> userPerference = response.getBody();
} catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
    String errorBody = e.getResponseBodyAsString();
}
```

If you need some more special handling on the error, you can try to implement a custom `ResponseErrorHandler`.

**Edited**:

Following is a code example for demonstration:

A test `RestController` have a `RequestMapping` which will throw an exception if request path is "/test?error=true". Otherwise, return a `List<String>` response:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getData(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error) {
        if (error != null && error.equals("true")) {
            throw new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } else {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add("test");
            return new ResponseEntity<List<String>>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Exception Message", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

A test configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestConfig {

}
```

The integration test that have 2 test cases. One is to test to get a List response, another is to test to get a message body from error response:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
public class IntegrationTest {

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    int port;

    final RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

    @Test
    public void testGetListResponse() {
        String url = "http://localhost:" + port + "/test";
        ResponseEntity<List<String>> response = template.exchange(
                url, HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {});
        List<String> list = response.getBody();
        Assert.assertEquals(list.size(), 1);
        Assert.assertEquals(list.get(0), "test");
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetErrorResponse() {
        String url = "http://localhost:" + port + "/test?error=true";
        String errorBody = null;
        try {
            ResponseEntity<List<String>> response = template.exchange(
                    url, HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {
                    });
        } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
            errorBody = e.getResponseBodyAsString();
        }
        Assert.assertEquals(errorBody, "Exception Message");
    }
}
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: the exception thrown is - RestClientException and not HttpStatusCodeException unfortunately. There is no getResponseBodyAsString for RestClientException. I just need to get one string back to the calling class. The code you have provided, I've used the same but that fails with a RestClientException when there is a RuntimeException on the REST server.

Comment: What is your RestClientException? Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
 at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:503)

Comment: This is the standard HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND exception. I have debugged to see that the exception object does not contain the RuntimeException details thrown inside the REST Service.

Comment: Sorry, I had changed from INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR to NOT_FOUND . But the result is the same I get a 500 error instead of the 404.

Comment: According to http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/HttpClientErrorException.html, `HttpClientErrorException` is a subclass of `org.springframework.web.client.HttpStatusCodeException`. Can you check your import class?

Comment: Even so, the original exception (RuntimeException) is not wrapped into the REST exception. The status code is 404 and the status text is Not Found. Which doesn't help in this case because the actual Error message stays back in the REST method.

Comment: I updated my answer with a code example to you for reference.

Comment: You are the man @wilson. Works like a charm. your updated code snippet was super helpful. Thanks a lot!